# jQuery Repeat (clone?) HTML for Dev

Tags: jquery

I'm using dummy content for a dev site that has about 100 rows or the same HTML - i.e.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    Content
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    Content
   </div>
  <div class="row">
    Content
   </div>
   ... up to 100
</div>
```

Instead of manually pasting in multiple rows, is there a way to clone that .row div with jQuery and add it to the container x number of times for dev purposes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery's [clone method?](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
var row = $('.row');
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
   $('.container').append(row.clone())
```

Comment: `container` is a class so use class selector instead.